# Why can't I overwrite the prototype of `Array` (`Array.prototype`)?

Tags: javascript

I set the prototype of `Array` as an instance of **`my`**, I think `book.aa` will display `"aa"`, but it displays `"undefined"`, why? Thanks!

```
   <html>
    <head>
        <title>Array Properties</title>
        <h2>Array Properties</h2>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function my() {
                this.aa = 'aa';
            }
            Array.prototype = new my();
            Array.prototype.bb = "bb";
            var book = new Array();  
            book[0] = "War and Peace";  

        </script>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="lightblue">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.write(book.aa+book.bb);
        </script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot assign to `Array.prototype` because `prototype` is a read-only property of `Array`.

So when you write

```
Array.prototype = new my();
```

nothing happens.  To see why, try

```
JSON.stringify(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Array, "prototype"))
```

The result is

```
"{"value":[],"writable":false,"enumerable":false,"configurable":false}"
```

Unless you are in strict mode, the assignment silently fails.

That's why -- and see http://jsfiddle.net/5Ysub/ -- if you execute

```
function my() {
    this.aa = 'aa';
}
Array.prototype = new my();
Array.prototype.bb = "bb";
var book = new Array();
book[0] = "War and Peace";
document.write(book.aa+book.bb);
```

You get

```
undefinedbb
```

The `bb` works because you have assigned to the *real* `Array.prototype` when you created and set the `bb` property.

It is a good thing that `Array.prototype` cannot be whacked, IMHO. :)

Answer (score 0):

Even if you *could* override Array.prototype directly like that, you would lose access to all the built-in methods such as splice, slice, push, shift, pop, unshift, sort, reverse and many others... So it would be terrible coding practice. But it doesn't work as Ray pointed out because it is read only.

This tiny code piece will demonstrate that Array.prototype cannot be overridden because the `sort` method will still execute:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Array.prototype={};
var a=new Array(1,4,5,7,8);
a.sort();
alert(a.join(","));
</script>
```

If you want to override prototype properties for Array.prototype, you must do it one at a time like so:
`Array.prototype.aa='aa';`

If you want to apply a large amount of properties to Array.prototype, then apply it through a loop. Here is some code I wrote for you which should accomplish exactly what you are trying to do:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function my()
{
    this.aa = 'aa';
}
my.prototype.bb = "bb";
var instance = new my();
for(var j in instance)
{
    if(instance.hasOwnProperty(j) || j in my.prototype)
    {
        Array.prototype[j]=instance[j];
    }
}

var book=new Array();
book[0]="War and Peace";
alert(book.aa);//alerts "aa"
alert(book.bb);//alerts "bb"
</script>
```